# Qual a utilidade das funções pipe() e map() no Angular 6?

Tags: angular, api, rest, typescript, http

Aprendi que tenho que usar essas duas funções quando estou trabalhando com requisições Http, aprendi que tem que usar essas duas funções como uma receita de bolo, da qual você usa e pronto, queria saber o porque de usar ela.

Exemplo de uma utilização das duas funções:

```
    public pesquisaOferta(termo: string): Observable<Oferta[]> {
    return this.http.get(URL_API + "?descricao_oferta_like=" + termo)
    .pipe(
        retry(10),
        map((response: any) => {
            return response
        })
    )
}
```

Se eu não me engano, ja vi a utilização das duas funções de outra maneira, mas estou alinenado do porque de usar elas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A função `pipe()` serve para ler dados de uma fonte assim que eles vão se tornando disponíveis e escrever esses dados em outro local.

Por exemplo, no seu exemplo de requisição HTTP você faz a requisição e os dados vão chegando aos poucos, conforme cada pedaço desse dado chega, ele se torna disponível dentro da função `pipe()`

A função `map()` cria um novo `array` com os dados do array que ela mapeia, iterando sobre cada elemento. É muito utilizada para realizar ações de acordo com cada elemento.

[Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552328/in-angular-rxjs-when-should-i-use-pipe-vs-map) do Stackoverflow, você consegue ler mais sobre algumas vantagens específicas sobre o porquê de usar essas duas funções.

Comment: Especificou de forma simples as duas funções. Obrigado

Comment: No contexto do exemplo que dei acima, o `pipe()` pega as informações do `get()` e deixa disponível para o `map()` ?

Comment: @ErickLuz exato.

Comment: @Felipe, uma dúvida. Como eu faço para "Aguardar o Map" fazer o trabalho dele para poder prosseguir com o meu código ?